# Python matrices print double line after every 3 numbers for sudoku

Tags: python, matrix

For printing a Sudoku grid I need a double line `║` to print after every 3 numbers for building the grid.

I am providing a simplified version of what I'm trying to do, please provide a better solution/alternative.

```
a = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
boolcheck = False

for i in range(4):  # rows
    for j in range(4):  # columns
        if a[i][j] == 0:
            a[i][j] = (i, j)
        print("│ ", end="")
        print(a[i][j], end=" ")
        if j == 2:
            boolcheck = True
        else:
            boolcheck = False
    if boolcheck:
        print("║")
    else:
        print("│")
```

Currently my output is as follows

```
    │ (0, 0) │ (0, 1) │ (0, 2) │ (0, 3) │
    │ (1, 0) │ (1, 1) │ (1, 2) │ (1, 3) │
    │ (2, 0) │ (2, 1) │ (2, 2) │ (2, 3) │
    │ (3, 0) │ (3, 1) │ (3, 2) │ (3, 3) │
```

Expected output is as follows

```
    │ (0, 0) │ (0, 1) │ (0, 2) ║ (0, 3) │
    │ (1, 0) │ (1, 1) │ (1, 2) ║ (1, 3) │
    │ (2, 0) │ (2, 1) │ (2, 2) ║ (2, 3) │
    │ (3, 0) │ (3, 1) │ (3, 2) ║ (3, 3) │
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is indentation, in fact as you can see in your code you will never enter in your `if boolcheck:`. This because the last execution of the inside loop will also have `j=3`, so will also assign to `boolCheck=False` and doing so will never print your wanted `║` double line character.

Otherwise if you put your code like this you will have your wanted output:

```
a = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

for i in range(4):  # rows
    for j in range(4):  # columns
        if a[i][j] == 0:
            a[i][j] = (i, j)
        if j == 3:
          print("║ ", end="")
        else:
          print("│ ", end="")
        print(a[i][j], end=" ") 
    print("│")
```

Comment: I need my boolcheck statement outside the ```j for loop``` Because then only my matrix will be print on a new line, otherwise it won't work

Comment: If you try to execute my code it will return the output you expected and without the use of the boolCheck variable

Comment: If you want you can testi it there: https://repl.it/repls/RemarkableFlamboyantReentrant

Comment: I have a doubt, why is the condition executed when ```j==3```? Should it not be 2? 3 is working the way it is meant to but I'm not sure why.

Comment: This is because after you printed (0, 2) in the third loop with j==2 you pass to the next loop (the last one), and the first thing you print is the double line as closing character for the third loop value that you inserted. In fact if you try to change range(4) in range(3) for j you will see that no double line will be printed.I hope that this answer your question

Answer (score 2):

There you go, I just added an if condition and removed others at the end, checking that boolcheck is true or false.

```
a = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
boolcheck = False

for i in range(4):  # rows
    for j in range(4):  # columns
        if a[i][j] == 0:
            a[i][j] = (i, j)
        if not boolcheck:
            print("│ ", end="")
            boolcheck = False
        print(a[i][j], end=" ")
        if j == 2:
            boolcheck = True
            print("║", end=" ")
        else:
            boolcheck = False
    if not boolcheck:
        print("│")
```